# Weblogic Workshop 9.2: _pageflow directory is not generated

Tags: weblogic9.x, beehive

At some point our WebLogic's Portal web project in Workshop stopped generating the WEB-INF/classes/_pageflow directory and all files in that. There are no visible changes in the project structure, but because of that all the Beehive page flow portlets are not working anymore saying they cannot find files from that directory. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a week of troubles we have found a workaround. Export ANT build script for given web project, execute its *clean* target, execute its *build* target and then it works again.